# How to exit from the script in R

Tags: r

I have a function like this

```
Squ <- function(x, expected.result){
result <- x*x
  if(result != expected.result){
    stop("We have some error /n/n")
    return(NULL)
  }
  return(result)
}
```

I am running below three lines.

```
Squ(2, 4)
Squ(3, 7)
Squ(4, 16)
```

Ideally i expected this script will stop in second line i.e.**Squ(3, 7)** as if condition is true in the function but it didn't stop & runs the script completely. How to write the script to get stop if conditions met true.

Thanks,
Mani

Comment: How do you execute it? It should stop if you source it for example in rStudio

Comment: Do you want your function to crash the interpreter or something?

Comment: Your function works for me.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, too. (Well, except that I think you mean `\n\n` instead of `/n/n`.)

Comment: Just to add that after a `stop` instruction, nothing else runs, the `return(NULL)` is never reached.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it works well if i source it in rStudio. but it doesn't work when i am run only those three lines alone only.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, running R code interactively means you'll keep running new lines of code even when there is an error. If you want the code to stop as soon as there's any kind of error, you should wrap the calls to `Squ` in a function. You'll have to edit the function if you want to save the values of each test, but it looks like you already know what each value should be and you're trying to find the first error. Using a function will give you the first error message and then halt execution.

```
test_Squ <- function() {
    Squ(2, 4)
    Squ(3, 7)
    Squ(4, 16)
    print("All code ran without throwing an error")
}

test_Squ()
# Error in Squ(3, 7) : We have some error /n/n
```

Let me know if you have a more specific use case in mind and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I got an idea from your answer.

Comment: Same case i have a script with ten lines instead of three lines in above script. Sometimes i will run all ten lines or particular selected lines. So that time i can't create function for that right? and if i run particular three or some n lines script wont get stop right? How to solve the problem in that case.

Comment: You can put however many lines you want inside of a function. There's nothing wrong with redefining a function every time you want to run it.

Comment: Do we have any other options without creating function to resolve this issue.